# Cherrypy render new jinja2 page after login

Tags: python, ajax, web-applications, jinja2, cherrypy

I have an application that I want to put behind a login page. I receive login information through ajax on the login page I load, then I want to load some data based on the user and render them a new page. I'm also using jinja2 to render javascript based on their user data.

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def get_data(self):
    result = {"operation": "request", "result": "success"}

    input_json = cherrypy.request.json
    value = input_json["anno"]
    print value
    return result

@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def login(self):
    result = {"operation": "request", "result": "success"}

    input_json = cherrypy.request.json
    uname = input_json["uname"]

    print uname
    tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
    imlist = os.listdir('app/public/clips'+uname)
    imlist.sort()
    print "loading homepage for user " + uname
    imlist = ['static/clips/'+item for item in imlist]

    return tmpl.render(salutation='User:', target=uname,image_list=json.dumps(imlist))
```

And my login script in `login.html` is:

```
function enter_login(){
    var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
        var tbtxt = tb.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "login",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({"uname": tbtxt}),
            dataType:"json"
        });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I render `index.html` with the given jinja parameters?

Comment: Jinja2 is a back-end templating engine. To re-render the page you'll need to reload  it. If you want to re-render the client side, you are gonna need some templating in JS (google for SPA frameworks or libs). Also, since you are probably rendering html in login method you do not need a json decorator there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this via adding a success function to the AJAX call:

```
success:function(data)
            {
              if(data!="")
              {
                $("body").html(data);
              }
            }
```